# -Wsign-compare warning in g++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have a code which uses comparison of 64-bit integers. It looks similar to the following:

```
#include <cstdio>

long long getResult()
{
    return 123456LL;
}

int main()
{
    long long result = getResult();

    if (result > 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
        || result < 0xFFF0000000000000LL)
    {
        printf("Something is wrong.\n");

        if (result > 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
            || result < -4503599627370496LL)
        {
            printf("Additional check failed too.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Additional check went fine.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Everything is fine.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When this code is compiled in g++ (tried different versions on Ubuntu 12.04 x64: 4.6.3, 4.6.4, 4.7.3, 4.8.0) with flags -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test I get -Wsign-compare warning for second line of the first if statement (output from g++-4.8):

```
test.cpp:13:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
 || result < 0xFFF0000000000000LL)
             ^
```

And when the test program is run I get two lines of text:

```
Something is wrong.
Additional check went fine.
```

When compiling same code on Windows using MS Visual Studio 11 Express Update 2 with default project options for either x86 or x64 architecture I don't get neither the warning nor this output, instead the output is:

```
Everything is fine.
```

Is it a problem in the code? If yes, could you point it? Or is it a problem with the compiler used?

Adding additional type cast for the second constant in the first if statement removes the warning in g++.

Comment: That's a nice first question, including a complete example and all relevant information.

Comment: `0xFFF0000000000000`, as a positive value, doesn't fit in long long. However, it does fit in an unsigned long long, so that's the type gcc uses.

Comment: The suffix `LL` can be used to force the compiler to chose a longer type (`1LL` is long long), but not to chose a smaller type, you want a cast for that (`(long long)0xFFF0000000000000` (strictly speaking this is implementation defined)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [lex.icon] in the standard, the hexadecimal-literal `0xFFF0000000000000LL` has type `unsigned long long`, because the value doesn't fit in a `long long` (see [Unsigned hexadecimal constant in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4737798/981959) and [C interpretation of hexadecimal long integer literal "L"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15510151/981959) for more information on this.)

This means G++'s warning is correct, you are comparing `long long result` to an `unsigned long long` literal.

Clearly as an unsigned value, `123456LL` is less than `0xFFF0000000000000LL`, so G++'s result is also correct.

MSVC seems to have a bug [Edit: or behaves differently for compatibility reasons, see comments], because this assertion fails:

```
static_assert(0xFFF0000000000000LL > 0, "big number is big");
```

MSVC gives the literal `0xFFF0000000000000LL` type long long, as shown by this invalid code that is accepted by MSVC:

```
auto i = 0xFFF0000000000000LL;
long long& l = i;
```

A C++03 example that should compile without errors is:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    unsigned long long& l = t;
}

int main()
{
    f(0xFFF0000000000000LL);
}
```

GCC, Clang, Intel and Solaris CC all get this example right, VC++ gets it wrong.

Comment: +1 for the nice ways to validate the bug using `static_assert` and auto type deduction :)

Comment: Does VC++ support `long long` as a C++11 feature, or as a C++03 extension? `long long` was not part of standard C++ before C++11, was it?

Comment: Under clang's `-fms-extensions` flag `0xFFF0000000000000LL` becomes signed. I believe this is because, as @hvd indicates, VC++ had `long long` before C++11 and this behavior is needed for compatibility.

Comment: @hvd, the question's tagged [tag:c++11] ([tag:c++] was only added later) and VC++ defaults to C++11, doesn't it? All the other compilers also supported `long long` (and `unsigned long long`!) years ago, the C++11 rules come straight from C99.  I didn't know about Clang's altered behaviour with that flag though, so it's obviously a known/intended behaviour for VC++, not just a bug

Comment: @JonathanWakely I wasn't asking about the question, but about the implementation. I was suspecting that VC++ used a conforming extension to C++03, rather than a buggy implementation of a C++11 feature. If you say that VC++ defaults to C++11 (I really don't know), rather than C++03 plus extensions, that answers my question, thanks.