# -Wsign-conversion Warning for Hex Literal

Tags: c++, c, literals

I ran into the following problem recently.  Since it is somewhat tricky, I have posed it as question/answer pair for the people of the future.

According to these questions ([Unsigned hexadecimal constant in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737798/unsigned-hexadecimal-constant-in-c), [C interpretation of hexadecimal long integer literal "L"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510151/c-interpretation-of-hexadecimal-long-integer-literal-l)) literals are fit into the first datatype that can represent them.  In this case, the list should be:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

This behavior comes from the C standard 6.4.4.1.  However, if you write the following code (I used C++) with `-Wsign-conversion` enabled:

```
int32_t mask = 0xFF00FF00;
```

. . . then one obtains:

```
<file>:<line>:17: warning: conversion of unsigned constant value to negative integer [-Wsign-conversion]
  int32_t mask = 0xFF00FF00;
                 ^
```

I find this strange because `0xFF00FF00` is the binary representation of the integer `-16,711,936`, which easily fits in an int.  What's the problem?

Comment: `mask` should almost certainly be declared as a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `0xFF00FF00` isn't viewed by the compiler as negative.  It has no way of knowing that you mean for the highest bits to be sign bits.

Instead, the literal is viewed as the *positive* number `4,278,255,360`, which doesn't fit into the integer's maximum value of `2,147,483,647`.  Hence, the compiler moves one step down the list, choosing the `unsigned int`, thus triggering the warning.

Comment: In fact *no* integer literal is negative.